# Call a function based on the device's screen size (hdpi/ldpi/mdpi)

Tags: android

On mdpi device I would like to call this method:

```
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
double height_px =  45 * scale + 0.5;
```

but I want to ignore the method when the app is run on hdpi devices, how am I able to determine the screen size on my class?

Comment: (1) What method - I don't see any? (2) You are already retrieving the density - so just check what it is: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: yes I dont wrap it on a method. I just wanna know, how am I able to do for example: if the screen size is 320dp then double height_px =  45 * scale + 0.5; how am I able to declare it??

Comment: But you already have screen density, screen height and screen width - so what's the problem?

Comment: Perhaps what you really want is a [dimension resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension). If you specify a value in DP then it will automatically adjust depending on your density.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah simply you can check for scale value like this,

```
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

And now you have scale value. The scale value varies like this,

For **MDPI** devices, scale value is **1.0**.

For **LDPI** devices, scale value is **0.75.**

For **HDPI** devices, scale value is **1.50**.

For **XHDPI** devices, scale value is **2.0**.

Just make a cross check,

```
if(scale <1.50)
{
double height_px =  45 * scale + 0.5;
}
```

Which means this code will not be executed for High and above resolutions.

Answer (score 6):

It's also possible to do sth like this:

```
int dpiDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
```

And then you can compare resulting value with constants from DisplayMetrics like this:

```
switch(dpiDensity){
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
        //Do sth for LDPI-screen devices
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
        //Do sth for MDPI-screen devices
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
        //Do sth for HDPI-screen devices
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
        //Do sth for XHDPI-screen devices
        break;  
}
```

there is also constant called DENSITY_DEFAULT but its value is same as DENSITY_MEDIUM.