# How to design app for Micromax funbook infinity and micromax A54?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created and application now i want to design for different screen sizes.I have Samsng Galaxy S2(hdpi 3.5 inch) micromax funbook infinity(7 inch) and micromax ninja A54(3.5inch mdpi) 
The Xml for S2 and micromax A54 is same but micromax is accepting images from mdpi both tab and ninja my problem is ninja A54 accepting images from tab(mdpi 1280x800) and xml from S2.
i am stuck please help http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range
[Supporting multiple screen size - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124079/supporting-multiple-screen-size-android)  [Call a function based on the device's screen size (hdpi/ldpi/mdpi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536701/call-a-function-based-on-the-devices-screen-size-hdpi-ldpi-mdpi)

Answer (score 0):

You don't always have to design XML file for all sizes,,Try to use `MatchParent` and `FillParent` in your designs